# SQL Server - Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, case

I'm almost certain you cannot do this within the context of the case statement, and I haven't been able to find any documentation about it, but is it possible to do the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN testValue > 2 
THEN testValue(Without Repeating it) ELSE FailValue)
END 
FROM Table
```

A better more thorough example:

```
Select CASE WHEN (Foo-stuff+bar) > 2 
THEN Conditional statement without >2 Else "Fail"
END 
FROM TABLE
```

I am looking for a way to create a select without repeating the conditional query.

EDIT: Due to a poor example on my part, and the lack of answers I was looking for:

```
testValue = (Table.A / Table.B) * Table.C Table.D

SELECT CASE WHEN testValue > 2 
THEN testValue ELSE FailValue)
END 
FROM Table
```

Comment: I'm confused by the answers with variables, as I don't see how putting this into a variable would help if the calculation involves columns. Does your `testValue` or `Foo-stuff+bar` query an actual column?

Comment: IT is a combination of a few columns. We'll say I'm amazon and I am selling something for $100(price). In my state there is a 7%(tax) sales tax and it costs $10(ShipPrice) to ship. So it would be something like `SELECT CASE WHEN (price*(tax/100)+ShipPrice>10 THEN (price*(tax/100)+ShipPrice ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @Elias I misunderstood the point in your question. I've added a second part to my answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like so

```
DECLARE @t INT=1

SELECT CASE
            WHEN @t>0 THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN @t=1 THEN 'one'
                    ELSE 'not one'
                END
            ELSE 'less than one'
        END
```

EDIT:
After looking more at the question, I think the best option is to create a function that calculates the value. That way, if you end up having multiple places where the calculation needs done, you only have one point to maintain the logic.

Comment: I was actually considering doing this, but it wasn't as smooth as I would hope, either way +1!

Comment: For this example, you don't need a nested case statement.

Answer (score 19):

The query can be written slightly simpler, like this:

```
DECLARE @T INT = 2 

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN @T < 1 THEN 'less than one' 
         WHEN @T = 1 THEN 'one' 
         ELSE 'greater than one' 
       END T
```

Comment: I edited your answer to make output string bit more logical and meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a way to create a select without repeating the conditional query.

I'm assuming that you don't want to repeat `Foo-stuff+bar`. You could put your calculation into a derived table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.TestValue > 2 THEN a.TestValue ELSE 'Fail' END 
FROM (SELECT (Foo-stuff+bar) AS TestValue FROM MyTable) AS a
```

A common table expression would work just as well:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT (Foo-stuff+bar) AS TestValue FROM MyTable)
SELECT CASE WHEN a.TestValue > 2 THEN a.TestValue ELSE 'Fail' END    
FROM a
```

Also, each part of your switch should return the same datatype, so you may have to cast one or more cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can use case statement Like this

```
select Name,EmailId,gender=case 
when gender='M' then 'F'
when gender='F' then 'M'
end
 from [dbo].[Employees]
```

WE can also it as follow.

```
select Name,EmailId,case gender
when 'M' then 'F'
when 'F' then 'M'
end
 from [dbo].[Employees]
```